# How can i decrement an NSString's Value from a UITextField Value input by user?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to decrement an NSString value which may hold a saved amount (Ex: 560.00)
and when the user enters a value into a UITextField Object, say, 50.00, the NSString holding the value of 560.00 decrements to 510.00 from 50.00 and still holds the Value without deleting the entire value or setting it to 50.00 ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your second part -  and still holds the Value without deleting the entire value or setting it to 50.00 ?

Comment: If you set your textfield value to NSString automatically it will set to newone then what is the concept of decrementing??

Comment: Well, that string in conjunction to the textfield is suppose to be updated as much if the user enters a value and therefore if the value is 20.00, it takes 20.00 away from the first value and updating the value to the new one. I am trying to do that but it just keeps deleting the string and setting it to the value i entered whicb is not what i want there :)

Comment: Question looks confusing. Please post some code that you are trying to achieve. That may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNumberFormatter` to parse `NSString` value to `NSNumber` and reverse. In addition it will allow you to handle user's locale.

Basic example:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *numberFromString = [numberFormatter numberFromString:userInput];
double valueAfterDecrement = [numberFromString doubleValue] - delta;
NSString *stringFromNumber = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(valueAfterDecrement)];
```

Comment: I am kind of new to this so how would i put this up ? do i replace the NSString with the NSNumberFormatter ?

Comment: yes, you cant do any math operations using a string, Convert it to number and do your stuff and display.

Answer (score 0):

here a basic example.

```
    NSString *string = @"50.22";
    float number=[string floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f",number);

    NSString *string1 = @"560.22";
    float number1=[string1 floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f",number1);

    float  ans = number1 - number;
    NSLog(@"%f",ans);

    NSString * finalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",ans];
```